# Java fails to load classes from CLASSPATH

Tags: java, classpath

I have a jar file with the contents (`$ unzip -l output.jar`):

```
Archive:  output.jar
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
        0  2013-07-08 17:57   META-INF/
      120  2013-07-08 17:57   META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
        0  2013-07-08 17:43   some/
        0  2013-07-08 17:43   some/package/
     1247  2013-07-08 17:57   some/package/Main.class
     2032  2013-07-08 17:57   some/package/plsql_o12_lexer$DFA22.class
     8022  2013-07-08 17:57   some/package/plsql_o12_lexer$DFA23.class
   212573  2013-07-08 17:57   some/package/plsql_o12_lexer.class
---------                     -------
   223994                     11 files
```

Contents of `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` is:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 1.6.0_27 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
Main-Class: some.package.Main
```

However, running the command `$ echo $CLASSPATH; java -jar output.jar`. Notice the CLASSPATH variable is set.

```
/usr/share/java/antlr3-runtime-3.2.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/antlr/runtime/CharStream
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.antlr.runtime.CharStream
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
Could not find the main class: some.package.Main. Program will exit.
```

Running the command `$ java -classpath /usr/share/java/antlr3-runtime-3.2.jar -jar output.jar` yields the exact same result. I have also tried `.:/usr/share/java/antlr3-runtime-3.2.jar` and `.:./output.jar:/usr/share/java/antlr3-runtime-3.2.jar` as classpaths, same result. The file `antlr3-runtime-3.2.jar` DOES contain the class `org.antlr.runtime.CharStream`, I have checked.

However, running `java -verbose -jar output.jar` gives result that contains the line:

```
[Loaded some.package.Main from file:/home/jan/projects/antlr-plsql/output.jar]
```

My java is:

```
java version "1.6.0_27"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.12.5) (6b27-1.12.5-0ubuntu0.12.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)
```

Why doesn't Java work the way it is supposed to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Other classpath settings are ignored if the -jar switch is used as per the [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html).

Answer (score 4):

Add the JAR to the `Class-Path` entry of the `MANIFEST.MF`, or add both JARs to your CLASSPATH variable and don't use the `-jar` flag.

Comment: So I'm supposed to add to my CLASSPATH every single JAR I'll ever want to execute? Really?

Comment: No, you generally set the CLASSPATH per application, from a shell script, or you add the necessary JARs to your application's `MANIFEST.MF`.

Comment: Another alternative is to build a fat jar that contains all it's dependencies bundled with it.

Comment: Your first suggestion works, the second probably does too, but is impractical (at least in my case). I've selected McDowell's answer, because his explains the behavior, even if it doesn't say how to deal with the problem. At least, I'll give +1 to your answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue as well.  I eventually figured out how to circumvent the issue.  So, the following is not really an answer that directly addresses your question, but it may work for you.

I wrote up a script that would compile (not just run) the code into a jar file.  It looks something like this (on unix):

```
rm filelist
find foldername | grep .java >> filelist
javac -classpath .:/path/external.jar -d ../bin @filelist
```

Then, in the directory where I want to run my jar file, I have external.jar there as well:

```
russell@ubuntu:$ ls
external.jar myfile.jar
```

That seems to work so far.

Comment: having posted all that, I think David's answer is the short version of what needs to be done.